# Fiberglass Bathtub refinishing keeps peeling

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, bathtub

My fiberglass bathtub is peeling again, and needs to be refinished again for the third time. It generally happens when temperature wavers between hot and cold I noticed (70 degrees to 40 degrees Farenheit weather within a day). When I step on the bathtub during the cold night, thats when it cracks. Its happened twice before. We are doing fiber glass refinishing. Are there any options to ensure it doesn't happen again? . Also, when a shampoo bottle or soap drops on the bathtub, it will create light cracks which may start peeling.

Note: Everytime its refinished/painted, I do not use the shower for 2 days, 48 hours.

[image]

Comment: What kind of surface prep are you doing before you refinish?

Comment: Agree with Ron did you just sand it? A gel coat is really needed if you sanded the old two far. I had the same problem with my first fiberglass boat where I had repaired some deep scratches, I found out about the 2 part gel coat I sanded again a fresh gel coat then painted, it held up well after that.

Comment: hi @EdBeal we are doing sanding

Comment: **A)** What's under the tub? Is it open to a poorly insulated crawl space? If so, insulate it! That may be insulating the whole crawl space, or just insulating the bottom of the tub, or even building an insulated box under the tub. **B)** Short term fix, run hot water in the tub to warm it _before_ stepping into it.

Comment: hi @FreeMan our bathroom does not have access to any ventilation crawl space, no vent, its an older building, how would a crawl space affect the bathtub peeling? its a fiberglass tub from the 1980s

Comment: "70 degrees to 30 degrees Farenheit weather" I presumed from this that this only happens when the temperature drops. That leads me to believe that the tub itself is getting cold and that's what's causing the problem. If the tub were above an uninsulated crawl space, that would lead to it getting cold, thus cracking. It seems that's not what you meant, so editing your question to clarify that bit and "temp wavers between hot and cold" (hot days, cold nights? General transition from summer to winter temps?) would help.

Comment: hi @FreeMan its 70 to 40 degrees within a whole day,  california can have days like that during the winter

Comment: That clarity helps. 30 degree temp swings don't seem that severe. Where I grew up in ID, we could have 95° during the day and 25° at night. High deserts are like that. ;)

Comment: hi @FreeMan yeah, this will be the third time it will be refinished, another comment, when a shampoo bottle or soap drops on the bathtub, it will create light cracks which also may start peeling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reliable option for ensuring it doesn't happen I'm **sure** of is the "rip out and replace" which is a major hassle and expense. Color me highly dubious about paint-type solutions here.

**However,** given *"When I step on the bathtub during the cold night, thats when it cracks."* there might be an intermediate step of refinishing while **also getting under the tub to properly support it** (I use plaster in the old-school way, polyurethane spray foam is a modern option I'm not entirely comfortable with and has to be done when you can partly fill the tub with water so the tub does not "float up" under foam pressure while the foam expands. Perhaps before the new paint job is best.)

If the tub surface moves when you step on it, it will crack. So if it cracks when you step on it, it was never properly bedded for support. Access for doing so may be difficult, or not (I've bedded one by going through the wall behind it, patching the wall afterwards.) Foam offers more options for dealing with difficult access. A properly bedded plastic tub (fiberglass, acrylic, whatever - or thin steel) should feel just as solid as a cast iron tub when you step into it.

Comment: added note to question, . Also, when a shampoo bottle or soap drops on the bathtub, it may create light cracks which may start peeling.

Comment: I agree with most of the points here. There are many fiberglass bodied cars that end up getting repaired & refinished and don't crack. I think the difference is likely in the fact that if you step on the hood of an older Corvette (don't know if the C8 is fiberglass like older ones) you're likely going to crack it no matter what temp it is. The key to the tub is to get it supported underneath. Once that's done, a good quality fiberglass refinishing _should_ last a long time.